# Passing Events and urls with @Input and @Output

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Total beginner to angular2 and not an experienced web dev, so I apologize for any extreme stupidity that is present in this question...

I'm having some trouble making a component for a dropdown select list.  My goal is to use this component in another component, and have a method in the parent component called each time an option on the select list is pressed.

Here's the template for the dropdown-input (child component):

```
    <div>
    <select>
        <option (click)="clicked($event)" *ngFor="let option of options">{{option.label}}</option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

And here's what the class for that looks like:

```
export class DropdownInput {
// List of options for the dropdown to have
public options: InputOption[];

// Url for controller method to get options
@Input() url = "/api/LogViewer/GetOpts";

@Output() clickEvent = new EventEmitter();

public clicked(event) {
    this.clickEvent.emit(event);
}

// Get list of options on construction
constructor(http: Http) {
    http.get(this.url).subscribe(result => {
        this.options = result.json();
    });
}

interface InputOption {
    value: string;
    label: string;
}
```

So from what I understand about what I have, each dropdown option has the 'clicked()' method bound to it on click. That method should pass on the event of the click to the method that the parent binds to 'clickEvent'.

Here's how I'm using this component in the parent:

```
<dropdown-input (clickEvent)="typeClick($event)"></dropdown-input>
```

And the parent component has this method inside the class:

```
public typeClick(event) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

Is this design fundamentally flawed or am I just making a stupid mistake? I'm not getting any errors or anything when running, but changing the dropdown options doesn't log anything either.

Second issue: is there a good way to pass in a url as an input to the dropdown-component? Just putting "[url]="/api/LogViewer/GetOpts" in the usage of dropdown-input gives an error.

Thanks!

P.S. Just to avoid the XY problem, I'm doing all of this because I want to create a component that basically is a panel of inputs (text boxes, dropdown selects, radio buttons, calendars) that I can create dynamically on many different pages (for use on top of a data table for filtering, etc). I guess this is similar to a form, is there a solution for this already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are listening to the (click) event on your option but you should be listening to the change event. You are also passing the actual event to your parent component while you want to pass the value that was selected. You can do this like this:

```
<select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
```

If you do this, the onChange method will be called with the value that was selected, not the actual change event.